# Does each library that statically links the C runtime have a different version of the runtime?

Tags: c, static-libraries

This may seem like the most basic question but I haven't really dealt with this sort of stuff, so I was hoping someone could give an explanation. Let's just say:

1. I have Library 1, and I compile it as a static library .lib, and in the compiler options I link the C runtime statically (on Visual Studio /MT flag).
2. I have Library 2 and I compile it in exactly the same way as library 1.

Then I have my program which is an .exe program/application, and in my application code I link the C runtime statically. Does it mean that my application's instructions on how to treat an std::vector (size, debug details etc.) or a call to 'operator new' or 'malloc' is potentially different from the instructions in the other two libraries? And also are the instructions in each library different from the other library?

Assuming I build both libraries and my .exe application in a consistent way, ie., all debug or release mode, are there still potential differences between the runtime classes and functions between the two libraries and my application depending on what runtime was statically linked when it was compiled?

If the answer if yes, and if dynamically linking the runtime for each library is the best solution what's the way to ensure that each library links the same version of the dynamic runtime library?

Comment: The path environment variable will determine which shared library is found first, that is if you have more than one shared library of the same name in your system. As for static, it's set in stone once compiled and linked.

Comment: C++ doesn't have an ABI. As a result, the best solution is to not pass standard container across library boundaries. And that sucks.... In practice, people are careful to have the exact same settings while building the libraries and then can pass containers between libs. So, the answer is "EXACT same build settings" and exact same versions

Comment: You'll get LNK2038 link errors when you mix.  Generated by [#pragma detect_mismatch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/detect-mismatch?view=msvc-160).  The C and C++ libraries use it to check for matches on the compiler version, /MT or /MD choice, debug or release build, iterator debugging level.

Comment: What do you mean by asking if the instructions may be different? If you have the same static library linked into two different programs, it is the same library. If the instructions in the library are not position-independent, they need “fixing up” when built into a program—they need to be adjusted for the addresses in memory where the parts of the library are loaded. But, in normal use, they function identically regardless of that address. Does that count as different (the actual binary data of the instructions differs) or the same?

Comment: Regardless of which version of a library you use, it ought to serve all of its documented purposes. If your program uses features from version 3 of a library, and version 5 is documented to be backwards compatible, that means all the features of version 3 will work in version 5, so your program will continue to work. You usually should not care which version of a library your program is linked as long as it is the version you designed for or later. What sort of “potential differences” in classes and functions are you concerned about?

Comment: @EricPostpischil I'm not sure. For example if I compile a library and it uses std::vector it obviously compiles the code that's the implementation of say Microsoft Windows Visual Studio at the time. Then a few months later I recompile my application and Microsoft's implementation of std::vector has changed, even has grown or shrunk in size. Then I can't really use that class across boundaries, right? I can't free a pointer to a std::vector that was allocated by the library, and I can't even assign it by value as in std::vector<int> appSideVector = getVectorFromLibrary(); Right? Generally I...

Comment: ... can't use it at all, as in appSideVector.doSomethingThatOldImplementationMightNotDo(). Am I right here? And is it also the case that by always linking to the runtime dynamically, /MD it means that every library that uses a class is guaranteed to be using the same version because it's getting its instructions/information about the class at program startup?

Comment: @Zebrafish: If you compile and build your application to use `std::vector` from library version 3 and somebody executes your application with library version 27, and library version 27 is specified to be backwards compatible with version 3, then it will work. For calls between programs and libraries, or between routines in different object modules generally, there is an Application Binary Interface that specifies how arguments are passed. Even if the routines inside library version 27 are different, it will accept arguments passed for library version 3, and they will work.

Comment: @EricPostpischil If both Library version 3 and Library version 27 compile the runtime statically, how would you know at the time of compiling Library 27 that it's compatible with Library 3? Ie., that the implementation of std::vector or std::string hasn't changed enough to break compatibility?